# How do I convert esp.flash_read() to string

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I have the following code:

```
  buff=esp.flash_read(esp.flash_user_start(),50)
  print(buff)
```

I get the following output from print:
bytearray(b'{"ssid": "mySSID", "password": "myPASSWD"}\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff\xff')

What I want to do is get the json in buff.  What is the correct "Python-way" to do that?

Answer (score 0):

`buff` is a Python [bytes object](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#bytes), as shown by the `print` output beginning with `b'`. To convert this into a string you need to decode it.

In standard Python you could use

```
buff.decode(errors='ignore')
```

Note that without specifying `errors=ignore` you would get a `UnicodeDecodeError` because the `\xff` bytes aren't valid in the default encoding, which is UTF-8; presumably they're padding and you want to ignore them.

If that works on the ESP8266, great! However [this](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/genrst/builtin_types.html#str-with-keywords-not-implemented) from the MicroPython docs suggests the keyword syntax might not be implemented - I don't have an ESP8266 to test it. If not then you may need to remove the padding characters yourself:

```
textLength = find(buff, b'\xff')
text = buff[0:textLength].decode()
```

or simply:

```
text = buff[0:buff.find(b'\xff')].decode()
```

If `decode` isn't implemented either, which it isn't in the [online MicroPython interpreter](http://micropython.org/unicorn/), you can use `str`:

```
text = str(buff[0:find(buff, b'\xff')], 'utf-8')
```

Here you have to specify explicitly that you're decoding from UTF-8 (or whatever encoding you specify).

**However** if what you're really after is the values encoded in the JSON, you should be able to use the `json` module to retrieve them into a dict:

```
import json
j = json.loads(buff[0:buff.find(b'\xff')])
ssid = j['ssid']
password = j['password']
```

Comment: This looks great. Unfortunately I’m going out the door for an extended vacation so I’m not able to try these. As soon as I’m back to the office, I give it a go.  I have a couple of other Python questions that I’ll pose then.